# Adaptive square block with text inside?

Tags: html, css

I need to display `div` element with text inside adapted for resolution of display. It means that properties width, height should be in percent.

I tried some ways:

```
<div class="one">
   <span>A</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.one { width: 3%; height: 3%}
```

It does not work, because width, height are set relatively parent element.

Another way is using padding:

```
.one { padding: 3% 4% 4% 3%}
```

It is better but not enough, because when I changed the scale of page I get ellipse instead circle.
So, what practice to use for solving this issue?

**In result** I need to get square block with `border-radius: 50%` and text inside.

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do, be more specific to the issue and create a simplified example

Comment: You should use `vw`, `vh`, `vmin` or `vmax` units for `width` and `height` and you'll get what you want.

Comment: Can you shere an example?